# Differeence b/w mostly fluid and column drop responsive design patterns

Tags: responsive-design

I can't figure out really the difference b/w mostly fluid and column drop responsive design patterns. Can someone help please.

Answer (score 2):

So that we're looking at the same thing, if you look at the [mostly fluid pattern](http://codepen.io/bradfrost/full/Iardn) on [this site](https://bradfrost.github.io/this-is-responsive/patterns.html) it's a multi-column layout that collapses to a single column layout at screen widths below about 500px ( 31.42em to be exact)

The key points are that the grids are flexible, and when it collapses the the columns stay in the same order. Also, at all viewports the order of content on the screen is the same as the order in your HTML

```
 1
2-3
```

becomes

```
1
2
3
```

The [column drop pattern](http://codepen.io/bradfrost/full/zhCwd) would most likely be a 3 column layout, main content in the centre and sidebars left and right at wide viewports.

For SEO reasons there's an advantage to have the primary content at the head of your HTML, so say your HTML looked like this

```
<main content>
<secondary content>
<tertiary content>
```

The column drop pattern will reorder your content so that at wide viewports it's a 3 column layout, main content in the middle

```
<tertiary content> <main content> <secondary content>
```

as the viewport decreases, this changes to

```
<main content> <secondary content>
<tertiary content>
```

and finally to

```
<main content> 
<secondary content>
<tertiary content>
```

Hope this helps!